# Need to create Binary tree structure

Tags: angular, charts, angular-nvd3

I want to create a top-down binary structure (as shown in the image) in my Angular-2 project. Which library should I be using for rendering such a structure. It must support - drag and drop feature to increase the tree structure.
[top-down tree structure image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kAIb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use angular-ui-tree npm

https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

and you can get woking example in below link
[Angular Tree component](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example)

Comment: Hi, I have checked these examples, but as you can see from the image I have attached I need a top-down binary tree structure.

Comment: ok, So on what bases you want  to define  order of your order ?